# How to get the topic probability for each document for topic modeling using LDA

Tags: scikit-learn, lda, topic-modeling

I use `scikit-learn LDA` to generate LDA model and after that I can get the topic-terms. I am wondering how can I get the probability of each topic for each document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `transform` method of the `LatentDirichletAllocation` class after fitting the model. It will return the document topic distribution.

If you work with the [example given in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_topics_extraction_with_nmf_lda.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-applications-plot-topics-extraction-with-nmf-lda-py) for scikit-learn's Latent Dirichlet Allocation, the document topic distribution can be accessed by appending the following line to the code:

```
doc_topic_dist = lda.transform(tf)
```

Here, `lda` is the trained LDA model and `tf` is the document word matrix.